# Create Windows Installation Media with Updates

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-update, updates, bootable-media

I often need to install a specific version of Windows 10 from a flash drive; however, the problem is that after I install it, it needs to install security updates from the internet, which takes an extraordinarily long time since there have been so many security updates since the release of this version.

I'm wondering; is it possible to install Windows from a flash drive with these security updates already installed (obviously not accounting for future updates)? If so, how?

Comment: Will take non-trivial amounts of time to maintain that because Microsoft can't goa week without at least one patch

Comment: @K7AAY, the main idea would be to have large bulk of them installed already to minimize the future number of updates I'd have to install afterward. I wouldn't necessarily need to update the installation media every time Microsoft releases a new update.

Comment: If Microsoft made it easy to download what you need, yes. However, you must find every update, determine if applicable for your version of Windows, then download the version applicable for your system.

Comment: Nlite is the best tool I have found>>>>https://www.ntlite.com/

Comment: You might look into disk cloning and mass system deployment, enabling reproduction of an up-to-date system and the licensing of its components. See https://www.g2.com/categories/os-imaging-deployment .

Comment: @Moab Had forgotten about Nlite. Moab, I hope you submit an answer as that's a much better solution.

Comment: @K7AAY Software recommendations are off topic here at SU. That is why it is a comment.